# Refresh a table after jQuery function deletes a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

A user opens a pop-up window with a list of files. Next to each file there is an icon to delete the file.

After the user clicks it, a new 'confirm-window' opens. After a user confirms, a 'confirm-window' closes, a file is deleted, but nothing happens visually and the pop-up window with the list of files stays open (the just-deleted file remains on the list even though it is gone).

If a user manually closes the pop-up window and reopens it, the list is updated.

I'd like it to automatically refresh after deleting a file without closing the pop-up window, by removing the row where the button was clicked.

HTML table in a pop-up window:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${bean.product.files}" var="na">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/productFiles/${na.id}.do">${na.name}</a></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="class" onclick="$().mkdelform('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/deleteFile.ajax?id=${bean.product.id}&fileId=${na.id}')">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete it!
                            </button></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

JavaScript function (deleting):

```
$.fn.mkdelform=function(action){
    $().mkdelformpost(action);
};

$.fn.mkdelformpost=function(action){
    $('#del-form').dialog(
            {
                autoOpen : true,
                height : 200,
                width : 300,
                modal : true,
                buttons : [{
                    text:msgcode['message.yes'],
                    click : function() {
                        executeActionPost(action);
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    }},{
                    text:msgcode['message.no'],
                    click : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    }
                }],
                close : function() {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pass the current button

You need to pass `this` when you call `mkdelform`:

```
<td><button type="button" class="class" onclick="$().mkdelform('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/deleteFile.ajax?id=${bean.product.id}&fileId=${na.id}', this)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete it!
                            </button></td>
```

So the function will be aware of the button which was clicked.

## Pass it further

```
$.fn.mkdelform=function(action, button){
    $().mkdelformpost(action, button);
};
```

## Find the tr descendant and remove it

```
$.fn.mkdelformpost=function(action, button){
    $('#del-form').dialog(
            {
                autoOpen : true,
                height : 200,
                width : 300,
                modal : true,
                buttons : [{
                    text:msgcode['message.yes'],
                    click : function() {
                        executeActionPost(action);
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        $(button).parent().parent().remove();
                    }},{
                    text:msgcode['message.no'],
                    click : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    }
                }],
                close : function() {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            }); 
};
```

Comment: All right, this works. However after I close to pop-up window it tries to save the product and I get the error that `product's version is not the same as bean's version (product's is higher by 1)`. It's probably because I also included there a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="version" value="${bean.product.version}">` which is not updated when the products' version is. So maybe there is a way to update the whole page / pop-up window to avoid this?

Comment: @MrP there must be a way to do so. You might be two hidden inputs, one for bean version, one for product version. Maybe updating the bean version to the product version does the trick. However, this is no longer a Javascript/AJAX issue (because that's solved by the fixes I have given), but rather a Java UI versioning.